# Best way to modify .htaccess SSL redirect to handle www and no subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Is there some way that I can modify this working `.htaccess` using some clever regex to handle the redirect for multiple subdomains.

Ideally I would like to be able to use my `joshmoto.wtf` domain without the `www` at the front.

Is it possible to make current `.htaccess` function like the below?

If you visit...

1. http://www.joshmoto.wtf it redirects to https://www.joshmoto.wtf
2. http://joshmoto.wtf it redirects to https://joshmoto.wtf

---

See below current `.htaccess` which always redirects http://joshmoto.wtf to https://www.joshmoto.wtf

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force SSL access
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.joshmoto\.wtf [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.joshmoto.wtf/$1 [L,R,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Any expert regex help would hugely be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: There are a couple ways to do this. You can replace the www or you can capture 2 groups and concatenate them. I'd give an answer for this, but I'm unfamiliar with .htaccess so I'm not sure if what sort of programming environment that involves. Are you just looking for a pattern that strips the www from the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Redirect HTTP with www to HTTPS without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.joshmoto\.wtf$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://joshmoto.wtf%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect HTTP without www to HTTPS without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect HTTPS with www to HTTPS without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.joshmoto\.wtf$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://joshmoto.wtf%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @wp78de, I added it in and it works. It didnt work quite how I asked it to function in the question but to be fair, maybe I am more favourable of the way your version works cause it always forces no www on the front :-) I thought it was a regex question because it could be accomplished all in one single block using regex, rather than three blocks like yours.

Comment: @joshmoto Cool. When it comes to redirects I favor safe rather than sorry. Glad to hear you like it.